# Are $c_0$ and $c$ duals of some spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

The (continuous) dual of a normed vector space is always a Banach space, but the converse is not true.  That is, not all Banach spaces are isomorphic to the dual space of some normed vector space.  For instance $L^1$ is not isomorphic to any dual space.

My question is, are the sequence spaces $c_0$ and $c$ isomorphic to the duals of any spaces?

Comment: Without choice it's consistent that $\ell^1$ is the dual of $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, I’ve heard that before.  But what is the situation with choice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preduals and $c_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125834/preduals-and-c-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c_0$ is not the dual of some normed vector space.

**sketch of proof**:

This can be proven using the
[Krein-Milman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem).

If $c_0$ was the dual of a normed vector space, then its unit ball would be weakly-* compact.

However, it can be shown that the unit ball of $c_0$ has no extremal points,
therefore by Krein-Milman it is not weakly-* compact.

**edit:** for $c$ the situation is more complicated than I initially thought.

As uniquesolution pointed out in the comments, its unit ball has many extreme points,
and it is not clear to me if Krein-Milman can be used to show that the unit ball of $c$ cannot be weakly-* compact.

Comment: The case of $c$ needs a little more attention, because there are many more extreme points than those you mentioned: in fact, every sequence whose entries have absolute value $1$ which is eventually constant (this means there exists $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $x_n=1$, for example) is an extreme point.

Comment: @uniquesolution thank you for that remark. I edited to retract my claim for $c$ until I (or someone else) fixes the argument or provides a new argument.

Comment: See the proposed duplicate question.  Note $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $c$.  If $c$ were a dual, then every closed convex subset of $c$ would have extreme points, so in  particular the unit ball of $c_0$ would have extreme points.

Comment: @GEdgar Wouldn't one need that the unit ball of $c_0$ is weak$^*$-closed in $c$ to conclude that it is weak$^*$-compact  and thus has extreme points? I don't see why norm-closedness should be enough.

Comment: Krein-Milman property, holds in all separable dual spaces: a bounded norm-closed convex set is the norm-closed convex hull of its extreme points.  Reference: Diestel-Uhl, *Vector Measures* ... https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3125931/442 ...